# Is there a reason for the differing behavior of the throttle operator in Combine and RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine

I meet some problems using the throttle operator in Combine, it looks like Combine's throttle operator doesn't throttling the first two elements of the asynchronous sequence.

The following is the code I wrote to verify this problem. For the convenience of testing, I defined a parent class to wrap the use of the Subject signal in Combine and RxSwift.

```
class MyAnyPublisher<Element> {
    
     init() {
         setupOperator()
     }
    
     func setupOperator() {}
    
     func send(_ E: Element) {}
}

class MyCombinePublisher<Element>: MyAnyPublisher<Element> {
    
     let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Element, Never>()
    
     private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
     override func setupOperator() {
         publisher
             .throttle(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, latest: false)
             .sink { value in
                 print("Received value: \(value)")
             }.store(in: &cancellables)
     }
    
     override func send(_ e: Element) {
         publisher. send(e)
     }
}

class MyRxPublisher<Element>: MyAnyPublisher<Element> {
    
     let subject = PublishSubject<Element>()
    
     private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
     override func setupOperator() {
         subject
             .throttle(.milliseconds(1000), latest: false, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
             .subscribe(onNext: { s in
                 print("Received value \(s)")
             })
             .disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }
    
     override func send(_ e: Element) {
         subject.onNext(e)
     }
}
```

I hope to be able to control the current limit of the asynchronous sequence according to the interval of 1s, and wrote the following test code

```
func testPublisher(_ publisher: MyAnyPublisher<String>) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        publisher.send("A")
        publisher.send("B")
        publisher.send("C")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        publisher.send("D")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
        publisher.send("E")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.6) {
        publisher.send("F")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.2) {
        publisher.send("G")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.4) {
        publisher.send("H")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.6) {
        publisher.send("I")
    }
}
```

According to my understanding of the throttle of RxSwfit and the actual building, RxSwift will print the following content

```
MyRxPublisher
Received value A
Received value G
```

However, the print result of Combine is as follows

```
MyCombinePublisher
Received value: A
Received value: D
Received value: G
```

Combine's throttle always seems to print the first and second elements no matter how I tweak the code and timing, does anyone know why?

My version information
Xcode: 14.3
iOS: 16.5

Answer (score 1):

The `latest` parameter means something different in the two operators. Set latest to true on the Combine version to get behavior that is as close as possible.

Unfortunately, the Combine throttle has unusual behavior when events come through very close together. Like what you are doing with your first three events. Personally, I consider this a bug. Sadly, it seems that Apple has put Combine on maintenance mode so it is very unlikely that they will ever fix/update it.

Comment: I changed `latest` to true, and Combine will output [C, F, I], RxSwift will output [A, F, I], still inconsistent

Comment: That's as close as you are going to get. The implementations are different and that's all there is to it. :-/